# Advice on extending DefaultServerRequestObservationConvention with request body data?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, micrometer, spring-micrometer, spring-graphql

Currently, with Spring Boot, all http requests are instrumented through Micrometer (https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/reference/integration/observability.html). However, for GraphQL requests, the contextual name is the following: `http post /graphql`. I would like to enhance this and add more information to it, such as the query and operation name, for example, `http post /graphql query#testQuery`.

However, I'm unable to get the request body data as it seems to be empty, yet `context.getCarrier().getContentLength()` is returning a non -1. Some advices how to proceed would be much appreciated.

CURL example

```
curl --location 'http://localhost:8080/graphql' \
--header 'Content-Type: application/json' \
--data '{"query":"{\n    testQuery(id: 23) {\n        result \n    }\n}","variables":{}}'
```

Java code

```java
package com.company.test;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.http.server.observation.DefaultServerRequestObservationConvention;
import org.springframework.http.server.observation.ServerRequestObservationContext;

@Configuration
public class CustomServerRequestObservationConvention
    extends DefaultServerRequestObservationConvention {

  @Override
  public String getContextualName(ServerRequestObservationContext context) {
    // Modify only /graphql ones
    try {
      StringBuilder requestBody = new StringBuilder();
      InputStream inputStream = context.getCarrier().getInputStream();
      BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));
      String line;
      while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
        requestBody.append(line);
      }
      // perform some string filtering here on requestBody
      String operationName = "query#testQuery";
      return "http post /graphql" + operationName;
    } catch (Exception e) {
      return "http post /graphql";
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: This won't work as  you can only consume the input once, if you would consume this it would break downstream.

Comment: Hi @M.Deinum, thanks for your reply. If this approach is not possible and can only be consumed once, what would you suggest to deal with the problem?

Comment: You would need a filter to wrap your request so you can read it multiple times (Spring comes with a `ContentCachingRequestWrapper` and response as well, which allow for this).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The HTTP observation is not the right place for that, as the HTTP instrumentation should not be aware of the type of request (GraphQL or anything else). As mentioned by Marten in the comments, to achieve this you would need to:

1. buffer the entire request body
2. read and parse it using graphql-java

This has significant performance downsides and will make HTTP observations inconsistent or brittle. There is already a [`"graphql.request"` observation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-graphql/docs/current/reference/html/#observability.server.request) for this.

Note that a single HTTP request can send multiple queries/mutations so the HTTP request contextual name would be hard to derive here.